# flutter sends http requests in a infinity loop

Tags: json, flutter, http

i want to use flutter to evaluate a json file. the http request also works and the data is also loaded into a map as expected. however, the app starts the request in a continuous loop that can only be stopped by exiting the program. i just don't understand why it does this.

The list jsonData is also filled with the correct and expected data and in the output of the program the data i put in the string is also displayed correctly. But as soon as it is done with the output, it jumps back into the fetchPost function and starts everything over again.

greetings niesel

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyState createState() => _MyState();
}

class _MyState  extends State<MyApp>{
  final url2 = "https://example.com/gartentemp/api/get_temp_data.php?data_type=temps_today";
  String basicAuth =
      'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('user:password'));
  var _postJson = [];
  void fetchPost() async {
    try {
      //final response = await get(Uri.http("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", "posts"));
      final response = await get(Uri.parse(url2),headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
      print(response.statusCode);
      Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
      print("map");
      print(map);
      print("/map");
      List<dynamic> jsonData = map["temperaturen"];
      setState(() {
        _postJson = jsonData;
      });

    }catch(err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //fetchPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fetchPost();
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _postJson.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              final post = _postJson[i];
              return Text("Title: ${post["datum"]}\n ${post["temperatur1"]}\n\n");
        }
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The Json-Content

```json
{
    "temperaturen": [
        {
            "datum": "2021-12-11 00:00:06",
            "temperatur1": "-1.06",
            "temperatur2": "3.56"
        },
        {
            "datum": "2021-12-11 01:00:06",
            "temperatur1": "-1.44",
            "temperatur2": "3.19"
        }
    ],
    "Aggregat_data": [
        {
            "day_avg_temperatur1": "-2.4",
            "day_avg_temperatur2": "2.11",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really ask a question, but the problem with your code is that you're calling `fetchPost` in a build method which then calls `setState` which causes the `build` method to be executed again.

As you can see, there's clearly a loop.

What you could do instead is make `_postJson` into a `late Future<Response>`, assign the future to this variable (without `setState`, cause the act of assigning a variable is synchronous), and in `build` use a `FutureBuilder` to display the data.

There's an awesome video description of how `FutureBuilder` works, I encourage you to have a look: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html